# How to change the value of sum function inside the query?

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I have a query with sum aggregation function :

```
SELECT sum(case when result=1 then 1 when result=2 then 0)as final_result From results
```

I want to change this part `when result=2 then 0` to something like that `when result=2 then final_result equals zero`

Is it possible to do this ? or there is another way for that?

Comment: In the comments somewhere you say _"with the values `1,1,1,1,2,1` the `final_result` as I want should be 1"_. Could you explain why the `final_result` should be `1`? Because from your question it seems you want `final_result=0` because there exists a row where `result=2`.

Comment: @funkwurm I meant th whole sum should be zero when we face 2 and it sums normally otherwise

Comment: Does my answer work for you? Or do you mean to say that when we face 2, the number goes back to 0 and starts counting again? So `1,1,1,2,1,1 -> final_result = 2` and `1,1,2,1,1,1 -> final_result = 3`?

Comment: @funkwurm yes it goes down to zero and start counting again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN cnt=sum THEN sum ELSE 0 END as Final_result
FROM
(
    SELECT count(*) as cnt,
           SUM(case when result=1 then 1 else 0 end) as sum
     from results
) Temp
```

Working [**Fiddle here**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f49c/7).

**Explanation:**

Inner query select the total number of records and the sum of the records. Then if those count and sum are equal that means all values are 1.

**NB:** Removed the checking `when result=2 then 0` because, the query will select 0 for any values other than 1. So there is no need to check for `result=2`.

**EDIT:**

To find the count of 10 consecutive 1's, you can do:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN RN=10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS final_result
FROM
(
SELECT CASE WHEN result=1 THEN @row_number:=@row_number+1 ELSE @row_number:=0 END AS RN,
       result 
FROM results, (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t
) Temp
```

Sample [**Fiddle here**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/334bf6/3).

Comment: Nope! Change the 5th value to a 2 and you get `5`. [**Fiddle here**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f49c/1/0).

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f49c/1
In this link I update the value `1,1,1,1,2,1`
The `final_result` as I want should be 1 here
but it shows 5
I want on each 2 value to make the whole sum zero??

Comment: @BaselShbeb: Updated my answer. Its working now. Try with the new fiddle link.

Comment: Change the `2` value to a `0` value and it gives `0` for the final result: **[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a85b8/1/0)**. You're asking to have the downvote removed but your code never checks for `result=2` when that is clearly the condition the OP gave you...

Comment: @funkwurm: OP wants to get the count of result having 1. The sum function will select 0 for any value other than 1. So there is no point in specifically checking for 2.

Comment: That works fine thank you. But I have a question about this snippet. is it possible to check for each 10 streaks. I mean each 10 continues 1s will add one to the sum unless we face 2 it will make the whole sum equals to zero

Comment: @BaselShbeb: Yes, we can do that using row number. But it will be a little more complicated query.

Comment: is it possible to help me by a fiddle link about that , If possible ofc

Comment: @BaselShbeb: It is a complicated query. Anyway, I will try on that. And it may take a while. I will let you know as soon as I crack it. ok?

Comment: @BaselShbeb: Got it !! Please find the edit part in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT case max(case result when 2 then 1 else 0 end)
           when 1 then 0
           else sum(case when result=1 then 1 else 0 end)
       end as final_result
From results
```

**[Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f49c/3/0)**

So what I'm doing is checking for the *final-result-must-be-0* condition inside a `MAX()`. That way, if **any** of the rows meets this condition (i.e. `result = 2`), the maximum value will be `1`. Then I can use that value to determine whether I wanna return `0` or do the `SUM()`.